# does stackoverflow support indieauth OpenID delegation

Tags: support, login, oauth

I've been following this post on [replacing-myopenid](http://peat.org/2013/09/15/replacing-myopenid/) and have setup a [github page](http://emeraldjava.github.io/) as per the instructions from [indieauth.com](https://indieauth.com/setup). I want to add 'http://emeraldjava.github.io' as an alternative open id url for my [stackoverflow account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55794/emeraldjava). Can someone explain why this login request fails?

EDIT

The [Login Request URL](https://indieauth.com/auth?me=https://emeraldjava.github.io&redirect_uri=https://indieauth.com/success) says

```
emeraldjava.github.io
This is not a supported authentication provider.
```

EDIT 2

OK I updated and setup my [openid.stackexchange.com](http://openid.stackexchange.com) account.

```
<link rel="openid2.provider" href="https://openid.stackexchange.com/openid/provider">
```

I've tried using the 'openid2.local_id' url when logging into [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) but it still fails.

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: added the error response code

Comment: See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/using-your-own-url-as-your-openid/

Comment: SQLFiddle appears to not work with SE's OpenID implementation at all. I don't know if that's a bug on their side or ours, but I would avoid testing with it for the moment.

Comment: thanks - i updated a ticket on the sqlfiddle issue queue https://github.com/jakefeasel/sqlfiddle/issues/43#issuecomment-37326332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at [the setup instructions for IndieAuth](https://indieauth.com/setup) suggests you haven't configured your site to point to a supported authentication provider.

Try changing:

```
<a href="https://emeraldjava.github.io" rel="me">GitHub</a>
```

...to:

```
<a href="https://github.com/emeraldjava" rel="me">GitHub</a>
```